What am I doing?

Recently I was doing something:
At the start of it I was in Japan. Then, I decided to go to Uruguay. After leaving there, I found myself in Slovenia. Later, I went to Turkey and found some large space. The next day, I appeared in Wales. Before I knew it, I reappeared in Armenia. A while later, I found myself in Latvia. Afterwards, I was in Kazakhstan. Soon, I travelled to Indonesia before going to Niger. To end the activity, I finished in Georgia.


So, what was I doing?


Hello, and welcome to PSE! Thanks for your puzzle. I would suggest to not give hints too early, especially when the puzzle is fairly easy. ;)

Nice puzzle!  Welcome to PSE (Puzzling Stack Exchange)!

You must be:

 JUST WALKING

Solution:

 As hinted by the "acrostic" tag, we read the first letters of all the country names.

